# Javascript use keyup to auto change min and max numbers

Tags: javascript

I am unable to remove the last digital `1` by using keyboard delete key as if `<= 0` then the value changes to `1`, so I have to select all numbers in the input and get the number changed? Thanks

**It is not an efficient way to change numbers.**

Is there a better solution to let me removing the last digit and enter numbers by using the keyboard.

```js
 document.getElementsByClassName('numInput')[0].addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
   if (e.target.value > 10) {
     this.value = 10;
   } else if (e.target.value <= 0) {
     this.value = 1;
   }
 });
```

```html
<input type="number" value=1 class="numInput">
```

Comment: You can check the value on `blur` instead of on `keyup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check for the `length` of your input value before replacing it by `1` with `e.target.value.length` :

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('numInput')[0].addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  if (e.target.value > 10) {
    this.value = 10;
  } else if (e.target.value.length && e.target.value <= 0) {
    this.value = 1;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" value=1 class="numInput">
```

Comment: Oh! Yes! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can see 3 different approaches here:

```js
function GetId(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

function SetNumberInput(e, min, max) {
  console.log(e)
  if (e.value > max)
    e.value = max; 
  else if (e.value.length && e.value < min)
    e.value = min;
}

const input2 = GetId('numInput2')
input2.addEventListener("keyup", ()=>{SetNumberInput(input2, 1, 10)});
const input3 = GetId('numInput3')
input3.addEventListener("keyup", ()=>{SetNumberInput(input3, 1, 10)});
```

```html
Min and Max in input tag<br>
<input type="number" min=1 max=10 value=1 id="numInput1"><br><br>
JavaScript add to input tag<br>
<input type="number" value=1 id="numInput2"><br><br>
Combined from above tags<br>
<input type="number" min=1 max=10 value=1 id="numInput3">
```

1. The first approach will turn red when you type your number out of your requested range.
2. The second approach will allow the user to increase the value out of your requested range.
3. The third approach is not possible to get out of the requested range.

Answer (score 0):

A number type input is HTML5, which means you can specify a min and max *on the element*. E.g. `<input type="number" min="0" max="1">`. No need for Javascript here.